# Apply Date Filter With "not qual to" Condition in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, date

> **i need to filter with a date column with not 
>   current month records**

i tried :

```
    $start = date('Y-m-d'.' 23:59:59',strtotime('-45 days'));
    $end = date('Y-m-d'.' 00:00:00'); 
    $collection = $collection
                ->addFieldToFilter('created_at',array('from' => $start, 'to' => $end));
```

this is Showing only Expect the this **two month records**

but how i can put "**Not equal to**"

Comment: What's your goal?

Comment: i won't need this month record how i can filter that???

Comment: order colletion ??

Comment: no custom table

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :-**

```
$start = date("Y-m-d h:m:s", strtotime(2019-3-1)); //Pass 1st month Starting Date
$end   = date("Y-m-d h:m:s", strtotime(2019-3-29)); //Pass 1st month Ending Date

$collection=$collection->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['gteq' => $start])
                       ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['lteq' => $end]);
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s), query was: SELECT COUNT(*)
WHERE (`main_table`.`created_at` != '2019-03-26 23:59:59', '2019-05-10 00:00:00'

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: but showing this month records

Comment: which record you want to display ???

Comment: GOAL :   I won't need this current month records...

Comment: without this month records...

Comment: i cant understand...you need current month record but without this month???

Comment: please explain with some example..

Comment: if  i have 10 records  with in 2 months

Comment: **1st month :4 Records ,
2nd month : 6 Records(Current month)--**

i want to filter 1st month records ???

Comment: using not equal condition ??

Comment: yes  but i am getting syntax error

Comment: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s), query was: SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE (main_table.created_at != '2019-03-26 23:59:59', '2019-05-10 00:00:00'

Comment: check answer  $start = date("Y-m-d h:m:s", strtotime(2016-3-5)) you can pass only 1st month date

Comment: found solution??

Comment: No .................

Answer (score 0):

There is a condition that you could give, just like how we use 'lteq' and 'gteq', you could use 'neq' which means not equal to.

```
$collection = $collection->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['neq' => $start])
```